# MemoryError while using cca.fit in Python

Tags: python, numpy, memory, scikit-learn

I'm trying to perform the Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA) using `CCA` imported from `sklearn.cross_decomposition`.

When I executed the following commands:

```
cca=CCA(n_components=1)

cca.fit(A,B)
```

The following error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processing.py", line 386, in <module>
    cca_implementation()

  File "processing.py", line 368, in cca_implementation
    cca.fit(A,B)

  File "/home/sandy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_decomposition/pls_.py", line 278, in fit
    tol=self.tol, norm_y_weights=self.norm_y_weights)

  File "/home/sandy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_decomposition/pls_.py", line 39, in _nipals_twoblocks_inner_loop
    X_pinv = linalg.pinv(X)   # compute once pinv(X)

  File "/home/sandy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 603, in pinv
    b = np.identity(a.shape[0], dtype=a.dtype)

  File "/home/sandy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 2054, in identity
    return eye(n, dtype=dtype)

  File "/home/sandy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 211, in eye
    m = zeros((N, M), dtype=dtype)

MemoryError
```

Where the dimensions of `A` are 38195 X 21, and the dimension of `B` are 38195 X 18.

Can someone help me in resolving this problem?
Is there any other way to find the `cca` more efficiently in Python.

Comment: `MemoryError` means exactly what you think it means: You ran out of memory.

Comment: I think so. Otherwise I do not see any other problem from the Trace and else part of the program.